# How to modify/develop the Go standard library in Goland without errors?

Tags: go, standard-library, goland

I would like to edit the Go standard library, so I can submit a pull request to the https://github.com/golang/go project.

I've checked out the source locally  and I've opened the `src` subdirectory as a Goland project.

I run into issues because Goland is still using my local Go SDK (in `/usr/local/go`). This means when I edit files that use an `internal` package, I get errors in the editor. Goland is first looking in my system SDK, before it considers the files in my project.

In the Goland preferences, I tried setting the GOROOT to point at my checked out code (in my case, `~/git/go`), but Goland complains "*The selected directory is not a valid home for Go SDK*".

I also tried setting GOROOT to "<No SDK>", but then Goland failed to resolve any types at all. Red error lines everywhere.

Any suggestions for how to hack on the Go standard library in Goland without errors?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html No IDE needed.

Comment: @Volker My opening paragraph is the background context, not the problem I'm facing. Did you read the whole question? I've edited that paragraph to hopefully remove the confusion.

Comment: You cannot compile the Go source or the standard library (neither are called "Go SDK") from within Goland, you have to call all.bash or make.bash anyway as described in https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html#testing and https://golang.org/doc/contribute.html#quick_test. Just stick to the official and supported way of doing things. Maybe read the whole Contribution Guide once more?

Comment: "*You cannot compile... the standard library... from within Goland*" Ah, ok. I didn't grasp that from the contribution guide (which I have read). Do you have any interest in turning your comments to an answer? I may not be the only person who makes that error in assuming an IDE can be used to develop the standard library.

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/how-to-use-goland-to-contribute-to-go.html